# Pandas groupby: add suffix to elements which are identical across groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                                peakID cytoband      start        end    length  10.388_116  10.193_156  10.401_184  10.214_385
0  Amp_2q37.3_chr2:237990001-242193529   2q37.3  237990001  242193529   4203528           1           0           0           0
1  Del_2q37.3_chr2:226990001-242193529   2q37.3  226990001  242193529  15203528          -1           0           0           0
```

Notice how `peakID` is different, but `cytoband` is not. I need to unpivot this table (using a function from `pyjanitor`) without keeping `peakID`. Currently I do:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyjanitor
from natsort import natsort_keygen

table = (
        table
        .drop(columns="peakID")
       .pivot_longer(index=["cytoband", "start", "end", "length"],
                     names_to="sample", values_to="state")
            .sort_values(["cytoband", "sample"], key=natsort_keygen())
            .remove_columns(["length", "start", "end"])
            .set_index("cytoband")
        )
```

And the end result looks like this:

```
table.loc["2q37.3", :]
Out[36]: 
              sample  state
cytoband                   
2q37.3    10.193_156      0
2q37.3    10.193_156      0
2q37.3    10.214_385      0
2q37.3    10.214_385      0
2q37.3    10.388_116      1
2q37.3    10.388_116     -1
2q37.3    10.401_184      0
2q37.3    10.401_184      0
```

The problem lies in the fact that if `cytoband` is duplicated in different `peakID`s, the resulting table will have the two records (`state`) for each sample mixed up (as they don't have the relevant unique ID anymore).

The idea would be to suffix the duplicate records across distinct peakIDs (e.g. "2q37.3_A", "2q37.3_B", but I'm not sure on how to do that with `groupby` or pandas in general as I need information from more than one group.

What's the cleanest solution to do this? [Existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966558/pandas-groupby-neighboring-identical-elements) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/add-a-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-to-a-pandas-dataframe)) don't really fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html?highlight=cumcount#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount) and a mapper:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
letters = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))

table['sample'] += '_' + table.groupby(['cytoband', 'sample']).cumcount().map(letters)
```

Output:

```
                sample  state
cytoband                     
2q37.3    10.193_156_A      0
2q37.3    10.193_156_B      0
2q37.3    10.214_385_A      0
2q37.3    10.214_385_B      0
2q37.3    10.388_116_A      1
2q37.3    10.388_116_B     -1
2q37.3    10.401_184_A      0
2q37.3    10.401_184_B      0
```

Or, keep peakID:

```
out = (
        table
        .pivot_longer(index=["peakID", "cytoband", "start", "end", "length"],
                     names_to="sample", values_to="state")
            .sort_values(["cytoband", "sample"], key=natsort_keygen())
            .remove_columns(["length", "start", "end"])
            .set_index(["cytoband", "peakID"])
        )
```

Output:

```
                                                  sample  state
cytoband peakID                                                
2q37.3   Amp_2q37.3_chr2:237990001-242193529  10.193_156      0
         Del_2q37.3_chr2:226990001-242193529  10.193_156      0
         Amp_2q37.3_chr2:237990001-242193529  10.214_385      0
         Del_2q37.3_chr2:226990001-242193529  10.214_385      0
         Amp_2q37.3_chr2:237990001-242193529  10.388_116      1
         Del_2q37.3_chr2:226990001-242193529  10.388_116     -1
         Amp_2q37.3_chr2:237990001-242193529  10.401_184      0
         Del_2q37.3_chr2:226990001-242193529  10.401_184      0
```